# Using scrypt key derivation function on OS X

Tags: macos, cryptography, scrypt

I like to use the [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) key derivation function in a C-like (Xojo, actually) program on a Mac.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing pre-installed on OS X in regards to this.

The original source code is on [Tarsnap](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html), and while it compiles (after `./configure` and `make`), it builds an executable, not a library I could link to.

I wonder if there's an easy way to build a dylib from this. I had a look at the makefile but it overwhelms me, and there's no build instructions along with the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to build a dylib with the help of Xcode.

There were a few challenges (based on scrypt v1.2.0):

- *sha256.c* declares a `initstate`. That clashed with a global name, somehow, so I renamed that to `s_initstate` in 3 places in that file.
- I added all .c files to the project but had to remove a few that are actually not needed, including *crypto_scrypt-ref.c*, which caused duplicate symbols others.
- The default search paths set up by Xcode 7 did refer to `usr/include` inside the OS X specific SDK folder. But that does not include the needed `openssl/aes.h` file, which I found only in `/usr/include` (i.e. at the file system's root). I worked around this by setting the target option "Always Search Users Paths" to `YES` and "User Header Search Paths" to `/usr/include`

After this, I could build the dylib and then link to the functions declared in *crypto_scrypt.h* and *scryptenc.h*.

(Too bad the project is not on a CVS or I'd submit a pull request with my changes.)

**Update:** The project is on [github](https://github.com/Tarsnap/scrypt)